# Regex to check for a repeating digit 

Tags: java, regex

I have a Java application where users must specify a PIN to log in. When creating the PIN, there are only 3 requirements:

- Must be 6 digits:

  ```
  \\d{6}
  ```
- Must not have 4 or more sequential numbers:

  ```
  \\d*(0123|1234|2345|3456|4567|5678|6789)\\d*
  ```
- Must not have a digit repeating 3 or more times (such as 000957 or 623334 or 514888): 
  This is where I'm stuck...

I have tried:

```
\\d*(\\d)\\1{3}\\d*
```

but I believe the `\1` is looking at the initial match to the `\d*` not the second match of `(\d)`.

---

Answer used:
I have updated to using:

```
\\d{6}
(0123|1234|2345|3456|4567|5678|6789|9876|8765|7654|6543|5432|4321|3210)
\\d*?(\\d)\\1{2,}\\d*
```

To satisfy the initially stated requirements plus a few I hadn't thought of! Thanks for all the help

Comment: This process as a whole, is something better done outside of a regex. *While cool, Regular Expressions are not your only tool kids.*

Comment: Your suggestion for how this should be handled?

Comment: What about `010203`?  That is, three or more of the same digit but not contiguous?

Comment: @AlanMoore that would be acceptable!

Comment: What about `3210|4321|...|9876`? Also, while you have that list, you can add `000|111|...|999`. Not elegant, I agree, but not that bad, as is pretty much the same as many `String.contains` (or its Java equivalent), so you can keep the banned sub-sequences in a collection.

Comment: @D.R. see answers by **winSharp93** and **gotafex**.

Comment: just a note: your are not checking for "more than 4 sequential numbers", it is checking for "4 or more sequential numbers"

Comment: @Kobi - Thanks for the suggestion! I had forgotten about descending sequential ones in my question! Is there any reason to choose (000|111|...) instead of   \\d*?(\\d)\\1{2,}\\d*   ?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger - Thanks for the heads up, I edited the question to state the correct restrictions: 4 or more sequential digits (ascending or descending) and 3 or more sequentially repeating digits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your regex is slightly off, since the first \d will match the first number. You only want to match 2 more after that.

```
\\d*(\\d)\\1{2}\\d*
```

should do the trick.

Quick edit:
If you want to match 2 or more numbers in sequence, just add a comma to your count, without specifying a maximum number:

```
\\d*(\\d)\\1{2,}\\d*
```

Or at least, this works in Perl. Let us know how you go.

Comment: That's perfect! I totally forgot that the first match counts! Brain Fart for the lose :-(

Comment: Also, you want to make that first \\d* non-greedy, it should reduce the number of steps to find a match in your regex, since as it is, it will scan the entire number, then work its way backwards through the string.

Comment: An example would have been good there :):

    \\d*?(\\d)\\1{2,}\\d*

Enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

Do you want to block three repeating following numbers or just more than three numbers in general (such as in "112213")?

If the latter one is the case, Regex might not be the best solution to a problem:

```
public static boolean validate(String pin){
    if (pin == null || pin.length() != 6)
        return false;

    int[] count = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < pin.length(); i++) {
        char c = pin.charAt(i);
        if(!Character.isDigit(c))
            return false;

        if (++count[c - '0'] > 3)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: A non-regex solution is nice, however the question did state that the answer should be a regex. If providing a non-regex answer, support as to why the answer may be a better solution would be helpful!

Comment: @D.R.: As stated, I wrote the solution to catch three identical digits in general (also non-repeating ones) as the question has been ambigious without the following discussion. This would not be possible with Regex IMHO. Maybe my code will help someone else than the OP who discovers this thread with a similar problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would :

1. Check length == 6
2. Check \d+
3. Frequency count each digit:

```
int[] f = new int[10];
int pow10 = 1;
int npow10 = 10;
int nmod = 0, nmod2 = n % 10;
while(i < 6) do
  int iDigit = (nmod2 - nmod)/pow10
  if(++f[iDigit] > 2)
    return false;
  pow10 = npow10;
  npow10 *= 10;
  nmod = nmod2;
  nmod2 = n % npow10;
  i++;
end
return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're doing three separate regex matches, presumably negating the result of the second and third ones.  In that case, this should do the trick:

```
pinString.matches("^\\d{6}$")

!pinString.matches("^.*?(?:0123|1234|2345|3456|4567|5678|6789).*$")

!pinString.matches("^.*?(\\d)\\1{2}.*$")
```

With the `matches()` method you don't really need the anchors (`^` and `$`), but they don't hurt and they make your intentions more obvious.  Also, the first regex ensures that all six characters are digits, so it's safe to use `.` instead of `\\d` as the space filler in the other two.

Answer (score 0):

Well your examples and your text do not match.  You say it cannot repeat more than 3 times.  000 is a repeat of exactly 3 times so it should be OK, but 0000 is a repeat of 4 which is more than 3 so it should not.  To match your text requirement, your regex should be

```
.*(\d)\1{3}.*
```

Which in a Java string should be

```
".*(\\d)\\1{3}.*"
```

This is similar to what you have, so maybe you're just misunderstanding the wording.

Note: I like this to test my regex in Java: http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html